# Dynamic Angular Checkbox Filter

Tags: angular, dynamic, filter

I am trying to make a filtering checkbox, where the options are based on what comes from the database. I cannot seem to find a solution where the filters are not hard-coded. The filtering in question makes little sense in this project, but I'm looking to get this working for a larger project that I'm working on. Here is my code (very incomplete, I was following some other tutorials I found, any help would be much appreciated! (I am pretty new to angular)
filter.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,  EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { ComicService} from '../comic.service';
import { Comic } from '../comic';
import { HttpClientService } from '../service/http-client.service';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() filter = new EventEmitter();
  comics : Comic[];
  filterList : Comic["name"];

  constructor(private router: Router, private comicService: ComicService, private httpClientService : HttpClientService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.httpClientService.getComics().subscribe(data => {
      this.comics = data;
    });
    this.httpClientService.getFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.filterList = data;
    });
    this.onFilter();
  }
  private onFilter() {
    this.filter.emit(
      this.comics
        .filter(opt => opt.checked)
        .map(opt => opt.name));
  }




  gotoFilter(){
      this.router.navigate(['/filter']);  // define your component where you want to go
  }
  gotoSearch(){
    this.router.navigate(['/search']);  // define your component where you want to go
}

}
```

filter.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let comic of filterList">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="options"
               value="{{comic.name}}"
               [(ngModel)]="comic.checked"
               (change)="onFilter()"/>
        {{comic}}
      </label>
    </div>



<div #comicList class="row justify-content-around">


    <div *ngFor="let comic of comics" class="card {{comic.name}} initial" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img style="height: 200px;" src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+comic.image}}" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{comic.name}}</h5>
            </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

http-client.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Comic } from '../comic';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) { 
     }

  getComics()
  {
    let username='kevin'
    let password='password'

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.httpClient.get<Comic[]>('http://localhost:8080/comics',{headers});
  }

  getSearch(string: string)
  {
    let username='kevin'
    let password='password'

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.httpClient.get<Comic[]>(`http://localhost:8080/${string}`,{headers});
  }
  getFilter()
  {
    let username='kevin'
    let password='password'

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
    return this.httpClient.get<Comic["name"]>(`http://localhost:8080/unique`,{headers});
  }
```

filter.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {

  constructor() { }
  filterByCheckboxes(comics) {
    comics.filter();
    return comics;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add in short what you want to achieve and what is the issue you are facing

Comment: I would like to show a list of the comics filtered by name. I wish to expand this to multiple properties (like an amazon product search) later but for now, I just want to understand how to dynamically generate a checkbox of filters based on unique values in the database and filter what is seen on the front end based on what is marked in the checkbox. For this, based on the comic book character's name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, share your `filterList`. Even better if you share what you have done so far in stackbiltz, as it is easier to help

Comment: It's difficult, because I'm making a call to my SQL database.

Comment: You can add dummy data in `filterList`

Comment: The filterList is an array of strings, such as "Iron Man", "Hulk" etc.